# Refresh current Row on Button Click in getView Android

Tags: android, listview

Inside my `getView` method in the `ArrayAdapter (BaseAdapter)` I have:

```
        expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateOneRow(pos, (Integer)v.getTag());
            }
        });
```

where **updateOneRow** is:

```
            rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 250; // row height (r.layout)
            expand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            collapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (mClickListener2 != null) {
                mClickListener2.onBtnClick(tag);
            }
```

**mClickListener2** is an object passed into the ArrayAdapter Constructor like this:

```
new BtnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onBtnClick(int position) {
            updateItemAtPosition(position, buildingLV); // buildingLV is my list view
        }
 }
```

and **updateItemAtPosition** is:

```
private void updateItemAtPosition(int position, ListView mListView) {
    int visiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = mListView.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
    mListView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, mListView);
}
```

Comment: can you please add more detail code?

Comment: Yes, what type of adapter do you use?

Comment: Trying to determine what you mean by update only this row?  Seems like you are already updating it in terms of height and visibility.

Comment: @AMY What are you unsure of exactly. I don't want to add unnecessary code

Comment: @Neo I am using a `BaseAdapter`

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado I mean refresh the view, without having to scroll up and down... I want to avoid refreshing the whole listView

Comment: @Neo Cheers man, my biggest problem is that most answers referenced the listView from the Main Activity, not the adapter

Comment: just for confirmation, using viewholder architecture or not?

Comment: @AMY Not, but am willing to change if needs be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the solution working for me -
Assuming you other code in your getView method - Add reference to your current row with button object using setTag.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    expandBtn.setTag(convertView);     
    expandBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View rowView = (View) v.getTag();
            // update you view here.  

            rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 120;
            collapsebtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    // Update only this row now                    

         }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Certainly the code you provided worked, and runs the method which references the list view from outside. But I think the method itself may be incorrect, though I got it from other SO answers

Comment: I'm certain the "Refresh" method is running with correct parameters when I click the button in the row, but it must be a flawed method then

Comment: Great, I got an idea.

Comment: But I think, you are added more penalties like "getFirstVisiblePosition()", "getChildAt". I am not sure - Is that anything wrong with keep parent view's reference with button's object. @GregPeckory what you say?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to approach it... I just copied and pasted from another SO answer... Is there an easier approach to updating a single row?

Comment: It's better to keep reference of parent(Row View) if you want to update itself by event generating through its child.

Comment: Could you show an example please... I'd be very grateful

Comment: Thats what I added in my answer. I added parent view's references using setTag "expandBtn.setTag(convertView);" to button object. And using it on click "View rowView = (View) v.getTag();"

Comment: I have updated question to show you my attempt, passing the tag. It still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @GregPeckory, have you tried notifydatasetchange? Try notifying listview after row layout parameters update

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do to the views will be one to the current item only.. now if in some cases should not be a listener... And you are recycling the items.. remeber to remove the listener